# How can I turn off proofing/spellcheck in Word 2010 for a single document?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, spell-check

I have a document that I open/edit often. I want to turn off the spellcheck functionality for this document, but *not* for all other documents (and I don't want to have to File/Options/Proofing every time I open it).

Is there a way to turn off proofing selectively (i.e., on a per/document basis)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a better way to do this in Word 2010 after getting so frustrated with this. This is ***THE*** way to go if you ask me when working with multiple Styles, etc.

- Open your document
- File
- Options
- Proofing
- On the right pane, scroll down
- Check both checkboxes to enable an **Exception** for grammar and spelling
  for your document

[image]

Comment: That's a better answer than mine, so I'll give you the Accepted Solution credit (which should also give you the rep you need to add pics). Thanks!

Comment: _Thank You_. Now I never have to google this again.

Comment: Great answer man, really helped me out there. Cheers !

Answer (score 7):

Here is one method I found that suits my needs:

You can modify the "Normal" style* for that document (which in turn modifies any styles based on Normal). From the Styles bar, r-click on Normal, select "Modify", click the "Format" button (bottom left), select "Language", and check the box labeled "Do not check spelling or grammar."

(A more detailed set of instructions with screenshots can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/acoat/turning-off-proofing-and-autocorrect-in-word-2007).)

* ***Not** to be confused with the Normal [**template**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us?correlationid=c8b5dd55-2999-43f8-a561-e80ba5a92452&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us), changes to which would effect all subsequent documents.*

Comment: Whooo hoo better descritpion than on MSDN it self.. blaigh me mate.. thanks