# MS Word Corrections

Tags: microsoft-word

MS Word will underscore with wiggly red or blue lines words that are not in the lexicon. When I click on "Ignore" or "Ignore all", the lines disappear. But they reappear after the document is saved, closed, and reopened. I have corrected some documents several times but they revert to the underscored versions seemingly automatically. How do I save the corrections?

Answer (score 0):

"Ignore" doesn't flag the document as "OK", so there's nothing in the document to tell Word that the spelling has been checked and accepted as-is.  So you can't "save the corrections", unless you make actual corrections with words it recognizes.

Word will try to spell-check every time you open a document, unless you [turn off Word's spell check](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T010804_Turning_Off_Spell_Checking.html).

You may also want to check out this similar SU question:

[How can I turn off proofing/spellcheck in Word 2010 for a single document?](https://superuser.com/questions/427974/how-can-i-turn-off-proofing-spellcheck-in-word-2010-for-a-single-document)

Comment: You can also add words to the Office Dictionary; the documents will no longer show errors on *your* PC, but will show them as typos on a PC without your Dictionary.